# Can C++ enum types be called as functions or it is just a different style of casting?

Tags: c++, casting, enums

I found the expression *enum-type-name*( *integral-value* ) in some library but it looked a little strange to me, Is it really what it looks like (at least to me)? that enum-types can be called as functions, or it is just another style of casting enums? or what?
for example:

```
enum SomeEnum
{
SOMETHING = 0,
OTHERTHING = 1
};

void someFunction(SomeEnum e)
{
// ...
}

someFunction( 2 ); // Invalid conversion
someFunction( (SomeEnum)2 );  // Works, Normal casting
someFunction( SomeEnum(2) );  // Works!! calling the enum as a function?? or just another style of enum casting??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well just as other objects, you can create temporary objects using a constructor. In this case you're passing a temporary `SomeEnum` object with the value of 2

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really helped, specially the "temporary objects" thing, actually it triggered me to search for enum default constructors, and I found this [link](http://lifecs.likai.org/2010/07/c-enum-default-constructor.html).

Comment: Glad i could help! C++ has some cool features out there designed to make our lives easier.

Answer (score 5):

That's just another style of casting. `(type)value` and `type(value)` are normally equivalent. The sole exception is when the name of the type involved consists of two or more tokens, such as `char *` or `unsigned long` (so `(unsigned long)x` is allowed, but `unsigned long(x)` is not).

Even in cases like these, you can create a single-token name for the type, and use it equivalently:

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;
a = ulong(x);
```

In any case, what you get is semantically a C-style cast. Most C++ programmers avoid these in general, as their meaning can be somewhat ambiguous. Depending on use, it may be equivalent to a `static_cast`, a `reinterpret_cast`, a `const_cast`, a combination thereof, or a cast that you can't do with a new-style cast at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
someFunction( (SomeEnum)2 );  // Works, Normal casting
someFunction( SomeEnum(2) );  // Works!! calling the enum as a function?? or just another style of enum casting??
```

Indeed, this is just another syntax for casting. Just like:

```
(int)2
int(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just casting.. Maybe you should use C++ style casting though

```
someFunction( static_cast<SomeEnum>( 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is a type in C++. So SomeEnum(2) is just a type cast. C++(11) brings enum class, which is a better representation for type, in line with OOPS terminology.